# (Woocommerce) Why is this shortcode rendering differently?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the add_to_basket shortcode where you specify an ID and on the page it simply renders an add to basket button.

Normal behaviour has just been, when the button is clicked it shows a loading icon and that changes to a tick to show the product was added to the users cart.

Now whenever I make a new product and use the same shortcode I am getting redirected to the products page every time.

I have placed 2 of the same shortcode on the page, just used one new product ID and one older Products ID and only the new product will redirect.

The older product works as it should - no redirect.

Looking at the markup the links are being rendered totally differently. The one that redirects is a standard href.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can stop it? I need it to not re-direct at all.

Why would it only do this for newer products?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Use to show products with add to cart button like this way. Hope it will work.

```
 $args = array(
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'stock'       => 1,
          post__in => array(50,100) //your product ids            
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <li>    
                <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) 
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ); 
                    else 
                        echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; 
                ?>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                <?php 
                    echo $product->get_price_html(); 
                    woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product );
                ?>    
            </li>

    <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply and thanks for taking the time but I really need the shortcode to work as it did before or at least an explanation as to why it has changed.

Comment: ok can you paste shortcode ? also woocommerce default shortcode you have added or is there any plugin?

Comment: You can see an example here. Notice how the code behind each button is different but the shortcode I have used on the page is the same except for the product ID.

https://iyengaryoga.org.uk/test/

Doesnt seem to have anything to do with product type or the options selected.